# How does common mode range include the negative rail?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, common-mode

How do the devices like AD8220 handle the common mode voltage equal to the negative rail or even lower voltage (Take a look at figure 30 of AD8220 datasheet) ?

Does the operation of the amplifier degrade if the Vcm be close to the end of its range? Or it will work good as long as Vcm be within the range no matter where in the range?

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2012/05/08/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/why-does-bringing-tl072-tl074-non-inverting-input-low-cause-output-to-go-high/234579#234579

Comment: @alireza: It's a good idea to capitalise your sentences and part numbers correctly for legibility and credibility. If English is not your first language you can add this into your user profile so we can make allowances - but what language does not use capital letters at the start of sentences?

Comment: @Transistor Chinese, Hindustani and Arabic comes to my mind. The first the third and the fifth most used languages in the world?

Answer (score 1):

We know what the conditions are for dual rails (±5V) and single supply (0 to 5V), so if you had one rail at say -2.5V and one at 5V then the common mode hexagon would be streched from the

[image]

Something like this: 
[image]

The hexagon or diamond plot is scaled with the Vcc range:
[image]
Source: [AN-1401](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwib7cXcg4zeAhWOw4MKHXLmCcQQFjACegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftechnical-documentation%2Fapplication-notes%2FAN-1401.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3QWSBFD1YHRjy8MaCHJ2rz)

> Although in-amps appear agnostic to the input common-mode voltage,
>   internally, they till must address this voltage. Common-mode voltages,
>   especially as they approach the supplies, can cause the internal nodes
>   to saturate when the external input and output voltages may otherwise
>   be within range. The diamond plot represents this imitation by plotting
>   the combination of every headroom limit, including the input range,
>   the output range, and the internal nodes. The diamond plot is a
>   boundary plot that shows he achievable output voltage (VOUT) range for
>   any given input common-mode voltage (VCM), or equivalently, the input
>   common-mode voltage range for which a given output voltage can be
>   produced.

Source: [AN-1401](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwib7cXcg4zeAhWOw4MKHXLmCcQQFjACegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftechnical-documentation%2Fapplication-notes%2FAN-1401.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3QWSBFD1YHRjy8MaCHJ2rz)

> How do the devices like AD8220 handle the common mode voltage equal to
>   the negative rail or even lower voltage (Take a look at figure 30 of
>   AD8220 datasheet) ?

It scales with the diamond plot, the negative rail would be the lowest voltage

> Does the operation of the amplifier degrade if the Vcm be close to the
>   end of its range? Or it will work good as long as Vcm be within the
>   range no matter where in the range?

The signal will not be a subtraction when the input signals are outside of the common mode range, so operation is affected. If you are in the common mode range of both the inputs then the instrumentation amplifier will operate as expected.

Answer (score 0):

How does the circuit implement common-mode down to or past the lower rail? They use PFETs, perhaps with the bulk tied somewhat above the lower rail, to raise the threshold voltage, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr50br.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>