# Op Amp Unity gain gives an unexpected constant saturated output

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I have this following circuit;
I use an Arduino DUE to send a 12-bit DAC output and I want to feed this in an Op Amp[image: schematic].

Every ground is tied to the same ground.
The Op Amp is [ADA4000-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4000-1_4000-2_4000-4.pdf) from Analog device.

The USB power is used and DUE (SAM3 series MCU) outputs DAC output to the Op Amp input.
[image: Osci]

I created a DAC signal that goes up/down from 1.55V. As you see the yellow signal (channel 1), this 1.55V is like a DC-Offset.
The blue signal (channel 2) is the Vout pin, the output of the Op Amp.

If you take a close look at the part where the values are lower than 1.55V from channel 1,
I was expecting the same decreasing pattern from channel 2.
However, that part is constant to 4.1V and I think the output becomes saturated.

I cannot understand this reason.
What seems to be the reason for this constant output?
I wanted a unity gain, but I cannot find the reason for this.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/why-does-bringing-tl072-tl074-non-inverting-input-low-cause-output-to-go-high/234579#234579

Comment: Datasheet page 1 "±4 V to ±18 V operation": you're giving it a single +5V supply. "±" does not mean "approximately", it means "both positive & negative" -> minimum 8V supply.

Comment: Then page 3: Input Charactersitics, Input Voltage Range: tells you that you can't apply an input any closer than 4V above the negative rail. Output Characteristics: tells you that it can't get any closer than about 1.5V to either supply rail.